# How to prepend a string to column names for dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe, multiple-columns

I'm trying to relabel some columns of a dataframe object in `R` using a certain tag.  I want to do a one liner like in 
In `Python 3` (and 2) I would do this:

```
tag = "id_"
DF_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)), columns = ["a","b","c","d","e"])
DF_data.columns = [tag + x for x in DF_data.columns]
DF_data.columns
# Index(['id_a', 'id_b', 'id_c', 'id_d', 'id_e'], dtype='object')
```

I tried it in `R` but I got an error

```
colnames(DF_data) = c(tag + x (for x in colnames(DF_data) )
```

This isn't working either

```
for (col_name in colnames(DF_data)){
    col_name = tag + col_name}
```

Comment: You can't add strings in R like in Python; you have to deliberately `paste` them together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to add your tag to the beginning of each column name? If so:

```
colnames(DF_data) <- paste0(tag, colnames(DF_data))
```

Comment: Yea that's exactly what I wanted to do.  Woah, what does it mean to add 0 to the end of paste?

Comment: `paste0` is a quick way to paste strings together with an empty character separator. It is the equivalent of `paste (..., sep="")`

Comment: See either `?paste` or `?paste0` (they link to the same place) for additional details.